# How do I send parameters from html code to ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I'm using Flask, html and Ajax.

html code:

```
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/_add_numbers', {
          a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
          b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
        }, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="a"> +
    <input type="text" size="5" name="b"> =
    <span id="result">?</span>
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="calculate">calculate server side</a>
```

Python Code:

```
@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)
```

I want to "**Text Input**" to remove,
How do I send parameters by the following code (html code) to function ?

```
<a href="javascript:void();" id="calculate">calculate server side</a>
```

For Example :

```
<a href="javascript:void();" id="calculate(10,15)">calculate server side</a>
```

Comment: (1) Have you searched for this on Google at all? There are *tons* of tutorials (like [the first hit when you search for "flask ajax tutorial"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/). (2) Are you trying to do this with pure Javascript, or are you open to using something like jQuery?

Comment: I have no idea what you think that will do. An ID is just an ID: it is being used by jQuery to bind to the link, but isn't sending any parameters. Where are you hoping for these values to actually come from? If you're hard-coding them, why can't you do that in the Javascript or even the Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in the `data-attributes`.

E.g. `<a href="javascript:void();" data-calculate-one="10" data-calculate-two="15">calculate server side</a>`

Just grab those values via jQuery and send them to the server side.

Comment: use the .data() method. and pass the name of the attribute (without the `data-` part) like so: `var valueOne = $('#calculate').data('calculate-one');`. Mind that the `a` should have an ID of `calculate` for it to work